# python regex date format, finding date only in 2012

Tags: python, regex, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python regex, date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076026/python-regex-date-format)

I'm writing an regex to find all dates like "June 27"

At the same time I only want "June 27" in 2012 but not in any other year

So "June 27th" in "June 27th, 2007" should NOT be found, but the regex does catch "June 27"

the regex is written as follows,

```
((?<!\w)(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december|jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|sept|oct|nov|dec)[\.]?\s{1,3}?((?<!(\d|:))(1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]|0?[1-9])(st|nd|rd|th)?(?!(\d|\s{0,3}am|s\{0,3}pm|:)))(\s{0,2},?\s{0,2}(2012))?(?!(\d|\s{0,4},?\s{0,2}(1\d\d\d|200\d|2010|2011))))
```

If I take away the "th" in "27th", the regex works, i.e. it does not catch the date string.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Can you give us an example of input and desired output?

Comment: Your current regex is much more complicated than what you're asking - i.e. it uses grouping, looks for other things, etc.  What exactly do you need your regex to match?

Comment: Agreed.  For instance:  Why lookbehind for not a word character when you can just match a word boundary?

Comment: What about `feb 31th, 2007`? regex is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming all your dates are in your given syntax, an easy regex would be:

`/^([^\d\s]+?)\s*(\d+)[stndrh]+,\s*2012$/`

the first capturing group captures the month in either language or abbreviation, the second capturing group holds the day of the month.

Alternatively, if you have to match all within a long text, try something like this:

`/(?:([a-z]{3,9})\s*(\d{1,2})[stndrh]{2},\s*2012)/`

same capturing but the regex is more restrictive, so it does not accidentally match unwanted results.